# Inter thread communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is my simple code, I want to get in the `console_task`, the value of the variable `i` in the `dialer_task`... without using a global variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include "console.hpp"

using namespace std;

void console_task(){
    console();
}

void dialer_task(){
    int i=0;
    while (1) {
        printf("LOOP %d\n",i);
        i++;
        sleep(5);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(console_task);
    thread t2(dialer_task);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, so the first question will be: What did you try so far?

Comment: Voting to close for Off-topic > why isn't this code working.

Comment: You should perhaps have a read of the help section of the site to give you a better idea of how to ask questions. This page might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: allocate a variable on the heap and wrap it using a std::shared_ptr, pass the pointer to both tasks, have a std::mutex to lock guard the variable if needed.

Comment: @AndersK., c'mon. Why do you need all this bloat?

Comment: @SergeyA well his example is simple but I got the impression it was his first steps building something bigger

Answer (score 4):

The constraint that there may not be a global variable to share the state between the threads leaves essentially 2 viable alternatives;

1. Allocate the shared state on the heap and pass that on to the threads
2. Allocate the shared state on the original thread's stack and "feed" it to the worker threads for shared use.

The catch to both solutions is to make sure that the access is appropriately guarded or atomic.

A simple solution is to use an `std::atomic` and share the reference between the threads.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

void console_task(std::atomic_int& j) {
    using namespace std;

    int i = 0;
    while (++i < 50) {
        cout << "task " << j << endl; // uncontrolled access to the console (demo)
        std::chrono::microseconds delay{50};
        this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
    }
}

void dialer_task(std::atomic_int& j){
    using namespace std;
    int i = 0;
    while ( ++i < 10) {
        //cout << "LOOP " << i << endl;  // uncontrolled access to the console (demo)
        std::chrono::microseconds delay{145};
        this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
        j = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic_int i { 0 };
    std::thread t1( console_task, std::ref(i));
    // a lambda with reference capture could also be used
    // std::thread t1( [&](){console_task(i);} );
    std::thread t2( dialer_task, std::ref(i));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

There is a catch to the shared `atomic`, it needs to remain valid for the duration of the threads (as it does here).

[Demo code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d07f998d04f8437).

Further heap based alternatives can be considered; e.g. using a shared `std::mutex` together with a `std::shared_ptr`.